# How do I launch the "SMB Browser" and point it to a Windows Print share?

Tags: samba, printing

I need to know if launching Ubuntu's "SMB Browser" program (pictured below) and pointing it at a Windows print server is possible.

[image]

I [tried using `ps aux`](http://pastebin.com/Xr42tXk1) to get an idea of what program is being used behind the scenes, but I couldn't find it, although I think its probably the GNOME CUPS print configuration app, since you can get to it from System -> Administration -> Printing.

I'm preparing a laptop image where users will need to be able to select a shortcut that takes them to the Windows print server and lets them select a printer in a (relatively) user-friendly way like Windows does.

I'd like to know if that is possible with SMB Browser. Failing that, I'd like to know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Never mind, I'm going to add the printers via CUPS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that I don't think that is possible.. Imho the best solution is to install all the printers on the image and then show your users how to change the default printer.

go to Preferences>Administration>Printing and right-click on the wanted printer and select "Set as default"